# whats the point of bracket after word import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
import { something } from 'something.js'
```

Whats the point of brackets after word import? i know that in ES6 brackets can work in two ways, either as closure or as object which will automatically set the key and value, but how it works in import case

Comment: Actually braces really just have one meaning - to define a block of code. Scope is actually a side-effect of them.

Comment: in that case it could work also without it, if it works in the case of default import

Comment: No, because the code that you are importing needs to be defined as its own block, hence the braces.

Comment: @ScottMarcus these curly brackets do not form a block. You will not be able to put any statements inside them.

Comment: haha i see there is lot of confusion on this topic so not only me i see

Comment: @NicholasTower You can't put statements in them, but they do form a block.

Comment: You must be using "block" in a very different way than i do then. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Answer (score 2):

That's how you do a named import. Something.js will have something like this in it:

```
export const something = 'hello'
```

if instead it had a default export:

```
const something = 'hello';
export default something;
```

Then you would import it using:

```
import something from 'something.js'
```

---

See also [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which uses similar (but not identical) syntax

Comment: The point is to import what something.js exported. If you want to import a named export, that's the syntax you use.

Comment: it seems to me that in my case it has no point that it is just some closure that is needed if there are more things to import like import { a, b } or import { a as b } etc

Comment: The syntax for importing a default export uses no curly brackets. The syntax for importing named exports uses curly brackets and the names of the things you want to import. So whether or not you use them will depend on what you're trying to import. These curly brackets are part of the syntax of the import statement; they do not make a closure. They serve a similar purpose as the curly brackets used in object destructuring (i linked to destructuring in my answer)

Comment: still i wonder why there are the brackets in one case and not in another why it isnt in both cases or not used at all, but ok you say it is in case of named exports to distuingish it

Answer (score 0):

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

```
// using.js
import { something1, something2 } from './somethings'


// somethings.js
const something1 = "1";
const something2 = "2";

export {
    something1,
    something2,
}
```